# Is there any method to use the MCMC method to estimate the measures of samples?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, sampling, inference, markov-chain-montecarlo

I try to explain my question clearly:

The MCMC method generates samples from a candidate distribution in the stationary state. In summary, MCMC generates a sample (*i+1*) based on sample (*i* ), $p(s_{i+1} | s_i)$.

Suppose, I have a function ***f*** that gets each sample as an input and returns back a real number as the output, and suppose that the time complexity of ***f*** is very high. In this case, generating samples $s = \{s_1, s_2, ... , s_{n}\}$ using MCMC is easy, but I am looking for a method, approach, research paper or anything that is about calculating the value of $f(s_{i+1})$ by using information of $f(s_i)$, i.e, $p(f(s_{i+1}) | f(s_i))$.

**Is there such a method or is there any relevant articles in this regard?**

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you mean: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/env.2405 (statistical emulators for climate models)